# how can i add event args? if i add inside System.EventHandler( , ) i get an error

Tags: c#, events, eventargs

how can i add event args? if i add inside System.EventHandler(  , ) i get an error.

```
class RadioButtonChecked: EventArgs
{
    private int m_ButtonNumber;

    public RadioButtonChecked(int num)
    {
        m_ButtonNumber = num;
    }

    public int ButtonNumber
    {
        get { return m_ButtonNumber; }
    }
}

this.radioButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton_CheckedChanged);
this.radioButton2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton_CheckedChanged);

private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, RadioButtonChecked e)
{
//do something...
}
```

Comment: Please specify the type of the error (compile-time, runtime) and the text of the error message.

Comment: This is not possible.  The event is generated by .NET framework code and it is only ever going to pass an EventArgs.  Use the *sender* argument to find out what button generated the event.  Cast it to RadioButton.  If necessary, you could use the Tag property to hang additional info off the control.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of your handler should be:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It should exactly match the signature that the Click event expects. You can still pass in your RadioButtonChecked (which by convention should be name RadioButtonCheckedEventArgs), since it derives from EventArgs. If you want to do something with the event in your handler, you can cast it back to RadioButtonChecked.

Comment: Hans Passant is right. Although my suggestion will get your code compiled, the system will always pass just an EventArgs into your handler function.

Comment: ok but how can i pass args into this function? it isn't possible?

Comment: Nope, not as far as I know. The system will call your function and you cannot get in between to add some extra data. If you follow Hans's advise you can store your buttonNum in the Tag property of the button and get it out of the Tag once you're inside the handler function.